# How to make a variable remain false after release of a button?

Tags: game-maker

```
left_click = mouse_check_button_pressed (mb_left)

battleMode = true

if (left_click) battleMode = false

if battleMode = false then {
  if (key_right) then {
  x= x+5
  sprite_index= spr_walking
  image_speed = 0.5
  }
}
```

`battleMode` becomes `true` again once left click is not being held. I tried changing `mouse_check_button_pressed` to `mouse_check_button_released` and `mouse_check_button`, but `battleMode` becomes `true` again when `left_click` has done its job.

Comment: I'm not familiar with game-maker, but shouldn't it be `if battleMode == false`?

Comment: @Xis88, no, GML supports `=` instead `==` also.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know GM really, but from the code snippet it looks like you are setting battleMode to true once every frame in the game loop.

is battleMode a member variable or is it inside a method being called every frame?

Make sure battleMode is set to true only once when it is instantiated at the point of creation, and then your logic should work

Answer (score 1):

```
left_click = mouse_check_button_pressed (mb_left)

battleMode = true

if (left_click) battleMode = false

if battleMode = false then {
  if (key_right) then {
  x= x+5
  sprite_index= spr_walking
  image_speed = 0.5
  }
}
```

I assume that the code you have pasted is used in a step event. Therefore whenever you are not pressing the mouse button battleMode will be true.
Be sure to instantiate battleMode in a **Create event**